# Repeat elements in a column given another value in the data frame

Tags: r

I would like to repeat elements in one column according to the values in another column. For example

```
col1 <- c("A","B","A","C","B")
col2 <- c(2,3,1,3,4)
data <- data.frame(col1,col2)
```

To give

```
col1<-c("A","A","B","B","B","A","C","C","C","B","B","B","B")
col2<-c(2,2,3,3,3,1,3,3,3,4,4,4,4)
data <- data.frame(col1,col2)
```

I tried the rep() command, but it only repeats col1 based on the first row of col2 ("In rep(c(col1), each = col2) : first element used of 'each' argument")

```
dat_new<-data.frame(rep(c(col1),each=col2))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We can replicate by the sequence of rows to expand the dataset.

```
 data[rep(1:nrow(data), data$col2),]
```